# Run Query with Data condition Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i have an other problem
***DBAdapter.java***:

```
public Cursor getTotalFlightTime_Custom() throws SQLException{
return db.rawQuery("SELECT time(sum(strftime('%s', Total_Flight_Time) - strftime('%s','00:00:00')),'unixepoch') FROM Flights WHERE Date BETWEEN '01/01/2012' AND '01/02/2012'",null);
}
```

***MainActivity.java***:

```
private void CustomReport(){
        DBHelper.open();

        TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblReportTotalFlightTimeAUTO);
        Cursor cursor = DBHelper.getTotalFlightTime_Custom();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String[] names = cursor.getColumnNames();
        String AUTO = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(names[0]));
    if(AUTO == "")
        txt.setText("00:00:00");
    else
        txt.setText(AUTO);

}
```

The problem is that the query is not working.
I wan the query to return the **SUM** from column **Total_Flight_Time**, table **Flights** in HH:MM:SS format for lines with **Date** column between *01/01/2012* and *01/02/2012* (DD/MM/YYYY). I had try YYYY-MM-DD format too but the program just crashing with no message.

I think i know where the problem is but i'm not sure:

```
WHERE Date BETWEEN '01/01/2012' AND '01/02/2012'
```

BUT i don't know how to fix it. The other part of the Query should be correct because i used it for the same column but the entire table and it works as i expected.

***EIDT:*** Data column is stored as **INTEGER**

Can you help me?
Thanks in advice:D

***Comment Code:***

```
String dateStringfrom = "01/01/2012";
            String dateStringto = "01/02/2012";
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Date convertedDatefrom = new Date();
            Date convertedDateto = new Date();
            try {
                convertedDatefrom = dateFormat.parse(dateStringfrom);
                convertedDateto = dateFormat.parse(dateStringto);

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(convertedDatefrom);
            System.out.println(convertedDateto);
            Log.d("Converted From","result: " + convertedDatefrom);
            Log.d("Converted To","result: " + convertedDateto);
```

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime` columns should be `numeric` and not `integer` for SQLite.

http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

You have to convert the string to a date for it to work in conditions.

`SELECT * FROM Table WHERE DateField BETWEEN Date('01/01/2012') AND Date('01/02/2012')`

**EDIT:** Not sure if this will help but give it a try.

`SELECT strftime('%s',Total_Flight_Time)-strftime('%s','00:00:00') AS TimeDelta, SUM(TimeDelta) AS TimeSum, time(TimeSum,'unixepoch') AS FlightTime FROM Flights WHERE Date BETWEEN Date('01/01/2012') AND Date('01/02/2012')`

Comment: i had try with Date as DATE but i have the same problem.
Also, can you show me how the all function should look like? * = time(sum(...)) and what else i have there?

Comment: or can i copy data between dates to an other table? if yes, how to do it?

Comment: @losif I'm not a big SQLite user, but `SUM` only works on groups. Your time expression might not be creating a group. You might have to assign the expression to an alias field, and than `SUM` that field. See my edit. At least it'll let you see the components of the expression. That might help figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @losif I'm also not sure why you're doing `strftime('%s',Total_Flight_Time)-strftime('%s','00:00:00')`. Isn't that just `X-0`?

Comment: is ok but i will try to move the data of the table between date 1 and date 2 to an other table and calculate the sum on table Temp

how t do i convert from String to Data? I had try a code but is not returning how it should instate of 01/02/2012 is returning Wed Feb 01 00:00:00 EET 2012
***Code in question***